# How to create a job post by email parsing in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, email-parsing

**I want to develop a job board website. I want specific feature in that is job posts will be created automatically by email parsing.**

I tried Zapier, but it creates only blog posts.
And tried postie plugin to, but Gmail didn't allow it.

Willing to use job monster / work scout/ superio any one of these themes. If you have any suggestions, please let me know about it.

Is there any way to parse the email data and create a new job post. Please help me to resolve this issue.

No paid task. Need help to learn the things

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot to unpack here.

1. The main problem you are going to encounter is that the emails you are parsing may not all be formatted the same. To pull the info out of an email you will need to be able to generate some rules to extract it.
2. If however, the emails are formatted the same then you can use the "split" function in Zapier to pull out the various bits of data from the email. Once you have these you can create a new post with your Zap.
3. I would recommend looking for a Wordpress plugin that allows you to create lists with custom post types. WP-Bakery does this from memory. You can set up a custom feed based on that post type.

Hopefully this helps narrow down the process for you. Good Luck.